# Size of electromagnet needed to replicate Earth's magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, estimation, geomagnetism

I guess the title says it all. How big of an electromagnet would you need to generate a magnetic field the same as Earth's? Like, what kind of amperes are we talking here? (Assuming a hypothetical superconducting magnet, of course.)

Answer (score 17):

You are in luck, since Osamu Motojima and Nagato Yanagi have already calculated it for you in their report [Feasibility of Artificial Geomagnetic Field Generation  by a Superconducting Ring Network](http://www.nifs.ac.jp/report/NIFS-886.pdf). They conclude that producing 10% of the current field is   feasible  using "12  latitudinal  high-temperature  superconducting  rings,  each  carrying  6.4  MA  current with a modest 1 GW of power requirement".

(The motivation for the report is the concern about the consequences of Earth losing its field during a geomagnetic reversal, but [it doesn't look like those are particularly bad](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/ab12eb/meta).)

Comment: Is this linear, i.e. can we extrapolate this to 100% of the current field?

Comment: I think so, although you may have to make the rings bigger to keep things safely under the superconduction limits.

Comment: Also, if mankind is ever going to terraform Mars, we definitely need an equatorial magnetizer! ;-)

Comment: @cmaster - One can put coils in the L1 point to deflect the solar wind at Mars: https://medium.com/our-space/an-artificial-martian-magnetosphere-fd3803ea600c

Comment: @AndersSandberg Seems like I forgot to add the <insider-joke> tags - obviously you don't know the game... Anyway, good to know that there are other potentially more practicable options :-)

Comment: Has anyone worked out if that is a feasible amount of liquid nitrogen to supply?

Comment: @cmaster i feel like you should put the game name somewhere for posterity

Comment: @beppe9000 - The game is the boardgame Terraforming Mars.